# Replacing the form with the return value from a php function using ajax

Tags: php, file, jquery, upload

I am new to both Ajax and Php. The code below is a form.

```
<div>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Username:</label><input type="text" value="" size="30" name="username"/> <br/><br/>
    <label>Chart type:</label><input type="radio" name="chart" value="PI">PI
                              <input type="radio" name="chart" value="BAR">BAR 
                              <input type="radio" name="chart" value="LINE">LINE    <br/><br/>
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"> <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  />
    </form>

    </div>
```

I need to hide the above form and call a Php function when the submit button is clicked. How do I do it using Ajax?

Comment: Why are you putting `htmlspecialchars` around `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`? And what have you tried to do yourself?

Comment: you can only do like this  <form action="">

Answer (score -1):

Its a basic thing you can get it easily when you go through google itself. Please search and if you didnt get post it here.

Anyhow, you can go by the following way using jquery ajax,

```
$.ajax({    
    type: "POST",
    url: "phpFunction.php",
    secureuri:false,
    fileElementId:'file',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){    
        if(response)    
        {
            //hide your form
        } else {
            //show error on your form.
        }
    }
});
```

In php file you have to receive and upload the file and return the status to success callback function..

Gothrough the following url,
[File Upload Using Ajax](http://www.scriptiny.com/2013/02/simple-file-upload-using-ajax)

Comment: You are missing the file upload, that is not possible in this way.

Comment: Yes, but you need to send the file to PHP first in order to be able to upload.

Comment: Are you clear on my answer now? If yes please remove that down vote. :P